# Find the volume $y=x^2 [0,2]$

Tags: volume

> Find the volume of the solid whose base is the region bounded between the curve $y=x^2$ and $x$-axis $[0,2]$ and whose cross-section taken perpendicular to the $x$-axis are squares.

My solution

$$V = \int_0^2\pi f(x)^2\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^2\pi x^4\,\mathrm dx = \frac{32}5\pi$$

But in the book, the answer is $\dfrac{32}5$. Why?

Comment: You are correct, and apply Fahrenheit 451 to that book if it contains many more mistakes...

Comment: There is no $\pi$; it is not a solid of revolution. See @Suburban13's answer.

Answer (score 0):

"whose cross-section taken perpendicular to the $x$-axis are squares."
You'd have to take small squares and integrate them over the region, so a small square would be $(x^2)^2=x^4$ and integrating them over the interval would give the volume they are asking in the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2061344)